# Decrypt the contents of a folder - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I've been tasked with making an encryption program and part of the task is to Encrypt/Decrypt a folder.

The encryption works exactly how I want but when I try to decrypt it gives me an error:

> *"Length of the data to decrypt is invalid".*

All I can say I've really changed is that I'm using `DES.CreateDecryptor` instead of the `DES.CreateEncryptor` in my encryption code. Though it looks like there's more to it than that for it to work.

Just wondering how I fix this really. I'll leave the relevant portion of my code below.

```
Dim folderinfo As New DirectoryInfo(folderpath)

For Each File In Directory.GetFiles(folderinfo.FullName)

    Dim outputFile As String
    outputFile = File

    Dim fsInput As New FileStream(File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length) As Byte
    fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
    fsInput.Close()

    Dim skey As String
    skey = Encrypt

    Dim fsDecrypted As New FileStream(File, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skey)
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skey)

    Dim desdecrypt As ICryptoTransform
    desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor()


    Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsDecrypted, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)

    cryptostream.Close()
    fsDecrypted.Close()

    txtDecrypt.Text = "All files decrypted"
```

Comment: what does this do: `If MyPass = Encrypt = True Then` ; you have some things that which should be disposed of too.

Comment: Ignore that bit. It's checking to see whether the password entered for decryption matches the one stored in a global variable when the user encrypted the file. There'll be a better way of doing that but I just wanted something to work for now. I'll take those lines of code out in case it distracts from the question. Oh right, what needs removing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done a classic mistake when instantiating the **[array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)**. An array should be instantiated with the size **(n - 1)** where **n** is the number of elements. To set the right size, all you have to do is to subtract 1 from the `fsInput` length.

```
Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length - 1) As Byte
```